# Calculating the spectral of integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Spectral theorem for compact selfadjoint operators

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{K}(H)$ is selfadjoint. Then there exists a system of orthonormal vectors $e_1,e_2,$... of eigenvectors of $T$ and corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,$... such that $|\lambda_1|\geq|\lambda_2|\geq|\lambda_3| \geq ...$

$Tx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lambda \langle x,e_k \rangle$ forall $x \in H $

Now I want to try this theorem on an example:

Let $Tf(x):=\int_0^1(2xy-x-y+1)f(y)dy$

My Problem now is the question of how to calculate the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: You put your hands in there! How is the proof written? What's its norm? But the good question is why do you want to calculate them?

Comment: Because I am trying to calculate the spectral and get to understand the proof.

Comment: The range of the operator is contained in the two dimensional space spanned by $1$ and $x.$ Identifying the eigenfunctions should be pretty easy.

Comment: If I remember the proof well, you don't have explicit calculations for each eigenvector, you just iterate the same process, but this process is not explicit. I think the goal of this theorem is to have properties over $T$, not to express it, otherwise you need a computer. In this case you can find by hand some (that's what I meant by put your hands in there)